# Google Maps marker do not appear on print

Tags: google-maps

I am using Google Maps API V3 for showing Google map. I created a custom control for printing the map. But when I'm printing it the marker is not in that print out. Can anyone tell me how do I print the map along with the marker ? Thanks in Advance.

**EDIT**

Code to create the map

```
function map_start(el,id){
$lat = $("#"+id).attr("lat");
$lang = $("#"+id).attr("long");
var image = "../assets/paleblue_MarkerU.png";
var myOptions = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng($lat,$lang),
  zoom: 12,
  disableDefaultUI: false,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
$map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('inset'),myOptions);
var placeMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng($lat,$lang),
  map: $map,
  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
  icon: image
});
var homeControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
var homeControl = new HomeControl(homeControlDiv, $map);
homeControlDiv.index = 1;
$map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(homeControlDiv);
}
```

Code for custom control to print the map

```
function HomeControl(controlDiv, map) {
 controlDiv.style.padding = '5px';
 var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
 controlUI.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
 controlUI.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
 controlUI.style.borderWidth = '2px';
 controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
 controlUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
 controlUI.title = 'Click to print the map';
 controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);
 var controlText = document.createElement('div');
 controlText.style.fontFamily = 'Arial,sans-serif';
 controlText.style.fontSize = '12px';
 controlText.style.paddingLeft = '4px';
 controlText.style.paddingRight = '4px';
 controlText.className = "gmnoprint";
 controlText.innerHTML = '<b>Print</b>';
 controlUI.appendChild(controlText);
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function() {
 printDiv('cboxContent')
 });
 }
```

Code for printing the map

```
function printDiv(divName) {
var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
window.print();
document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
window.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: You need to specify what platform your running the API on , iOS , Android, Web e.t.c.

Comment: I'm running it on web

Comment: How do you print the map? Marker is an element added to your DOM tree. Maybe you take the html of the map, but not the marker. Give some code

Comment: Added my code for creating the map, it's custom control and printing the map

Comment: I suppose cboxContent is you map container right? If it is give a link of your app, because I don't see anything wrong with your printDiv()